# Matplotlib different colors for bar graph based on value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, yahoo-finance

I'm plotting returns for sectors and all the stocks in them. I would like to have the values > 100 to be green, and < 100 to be red. Here's my code:

```
sector_lst = ['XLK','XLF','XLE']  ## etc.

for i in sector_lst:                   
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8)) 

    for x in sectordict[i]:                #sectordict[i] is all the stocks in a sector (so AAPL, GOOG, etc. for tech) 
        if pct_change[x] > 1:              
             pct_change[sectordict[i]].plot(kind='bar',color='g') 

        ##if pct_chg < 1
        else:                              
             pct_change[sectordict[i]].plot(kind='bar',color='r') 


plt.title(i)
```

So far this is returning the whole sector graphs as green or red; if the first value is > 100 all stocks will be green and vice versa.

My expected output is to have 11 graphs (which it currently does), but with different colors for each stock within the graph, if stock had > 100% return then it shows green and < 100% it shows red.

Comment: can you add few rows from your df ? for single sector

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After few tries with Pandas plot() I didn't find a way to achieve what you expect but you can easily do that with Matplotlib directly.

I hope this will help:

I created sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [2,6,2,4,5,3,7]})
```

and I create two temp df which will store only values satisfying the condition:

```
t1 = df[df['a']<5]
t2 = df[df['a']>=5]
```

and then just plot it :

```
plt.bar(t1.index.values, t1['a'], color='r')
plt.bar(t2.index.values, t2['a'], color='g')
```

the final result looks like this:

[image]

Is that what you expect?

Comment: this is what I want the graph to look like, but my sectordict[i] isn't a df, but rather a dictionary

Comment: If you will add some sample data I could help more, and customize this plots to your example.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve your result in a single call to `plt.bar` this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [2,6,2,4,5,3,7]})
df['colors'] = 'r'
df.loc[df.a>=5,'colors'] = 'g'
plt.bar(df.index, df.a, color=df.colors)
```

You also mention in a comment that `sectordict[i]` is a dictionary, but you can easily convert a dictionary into a dataframe with:
[`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html).