# How to colour all bars after a certain date in a matplotlib date bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-datetime

I have a dataset that consists of `datetime.datetime` objects in a list called `x` and a list of ints called `y`. I'm plotting them like so:

```
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.show()
```

How would I go about colouring all the bars after a given date another colour? I know I can get a list of bars by assigning the result of `plt.bar(x, y)` but I've never messed around with `matplotlib` beyond making simple plots.

Comment: For example `colors = ['b' if xi < x_special else 'r' for xi in x]` and then `plt.bar(x, y, color=colors)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib different colors for bar graph based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274183/matplotlib-different-colors-for-bar-graph-based-on-value) (see the second answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a boolean mask, where you return 0 or 1 depending on if the date is greater than another date. Then use this array to get a list of colors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np

base = datetime.datetime.today()

x = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(10)]
y = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)

greater = np.greater(x, datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 7)).astype(int)
colors = np.array(['red', 'green'])

plt.bar(x, y, color=colors[greater])
```

[image]

`greater` looks like this:

```
Out[9]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

And `colors[greater]` looks like this:

```
array(['green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'red',
       'red', 'red'], dtype='<U5')
```

Comment: Thank you. Just curious, why does the list of colours have to be a numpy array?

Comment: It doesn't, it just made it easier for indexing.